# Deleting rows in Excel based on Dictionary value in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I am still getting into VBA and currently I am trying to do the following:
- Delete rows in an Excel sheet based on a value stored in a dictionary.

I have this code:

```
For Each Key In dict.Keys
    i = Key
    Cells.Rows(i).Delete
Next
```

where before that I have populated the dictionary. The idea is that the "key" stores all the row number in which a specific value is stored, for example "1".

With the for each I want to delete all the rows stored in the dictionary, but once you delete a row in Excel the number changes. For example the first stored value in the dictionary is 5, so the for each will delete row number 5. The second value in the dictionary is 10 and now when the for each tries to delete row 10, it delete row 10, which in the original file used to be row 11. Basically the for each fails to delete the correct rows.

As I said I am new to VBA and I am not even sure if this is the correct way to do this or there is something better than dictionaries for this situation. I am looking forward to hearing your ideas and suggestions.

Thank you in advance!

Update: Solved by Ambie and sktneer. Check answers.

Comment: Sort the dictionary descending or start with the last row. This way the row numbers don't change during the delete process.

Comment: how to sort it ?

Comment: Write `Option Explicit` at the top of your code sheet. Then declare all variables, finding the correct data type. Select "Key" and click F1. You will be told that it is a word reserved for VBA. So, better don't use it for your own purposes. Finally, don't start your experiments with `For Each`. Build a `For   ... Next` loop first.

Comment: How can I go through Dictionary Keys with a For ... Next loop ?

Comment: A `For Each` is the easiest method for Dictionary. To use a `For Next` loop you might need to do something destructive like read item 1, remove it, read item 1... etc until its empty. (there are probably many better, non-destructive methods though!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd bother with the `Dictionary`. Afterall, a `Range` is a collection, so perhaps just consider putting all of your target rows into a range and run the 'bulk' delete on that range. It'd be far quicker than a delete by looping rows:

```
Dim delRng As Range, srcRng As Range, cell As Range

'Loop through the range containing your criterion test
With Sheet1
    Set srcRng = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
End With

For Each cell In srcRng.Cells
    If cell.Value2 = 1 Then 'change to your criterion
        'It's a hit so add the cell to our delete range
        If delRng Is Nothing Then
            Set delRng = cell
        Else
            Set delRng = Union(delRng, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next

'Delete the rows
If Not delRng Is Nothing Then delRng.EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it more dynamic? Currently I have 380 000 rows but this number might vary.

Comment: Of course. You just need to clarify your rule for defining the range. For example, if you wanted the range to be "A1" to end very bottom of your data in column "A", then you'd use something like my edited answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you :) I am testing both options now and I will update the question hopefully as solved after that!

Comment: Good for you. Enjoy your journey into VBA. Once you get the hang of loops and collections, have a look at reading a Range into an array. With a dataset of 380,000, an array would dramatically increase speed.

Comment: Hey, I have a follow up question. What if my rows don't have unique data. For example Columns A has 5 rows with "John" and in row 3 there is "1" stored in column B. How can I remember this 5 and delete it later on?

Comment: Post that as a new question, as the answer differs quite a bit from this question. Try to post some same sample data and explain quite carefully exactly what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this...

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim it

For Each it In dict.keys
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = Range("A" & it)
    Else
        Set rng = Union(rng, Range("A" & it))
    End If
Next it
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.EntireRow.Delete
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, man :) It worked perfectly but I guess I have way too many rows. The script was running for almost 5 mins

Comment: You're welcome. Then how did the chosen answer worke differently and faster? :)

Comment: Still working on it :D I will update it if it not faster. In the question itself I wrote that both of you solved it.